# mysqli_num_rows does not work after giving parameters

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to prevent sql injection by binding parameters but when I convert my code to binded parameters, the mysqli_num_rows no longer works.

I have a simple email authentication that I want to check against the database for duplicate rows:

Below **my code :**

```
    $checkDup = "SELECT Email FROM users WHERE Email='{$_POST['Email']}'";
    $resultDup = mysqli_query($db,$checkDup);

    //If not 0 duplicates (another one exists) create an error alert
    if(!mysqli_num_rows($resultDup) == 0){
        echo '<script language="javascript">
                alert("Email Already Exists");
                window.location.href = "Sign Up.php";
            </script>';
        unset($_POST);
    }
```

After binding it -

> Its Not right type error i got :

```
$checkDup = $db->prepare("SELECT Email FROM users WHERE Email= ?");
$checkDup->bind_param("s", $_POST['Email']);


//If not 0 duplicates (another one exists) create an error alert
if(!mysqli_num_rows($checkDup->execute()) == 0){
    echo '<script language="javascript">
            alert("Email Already Exists");
            window.location.href = "Sign Up.php";
        </script>';
    unset($_POST);
}
```

Comment: By the way you should use `mysqli_num_rows($checkDup->execute()) > 0` instead of `!mysqli_num_rows($resultDup) == 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use num_rows()

```
$checkDup = $db->prepare("SELECT Email FROM users WHERE Email= ?");
$checkDup->bind_param("s", $_POST['Email']);
$checkDup->execute();
$checkDup->store_result();


if ($checkDup->num_rows  > 0) {

echo '<script language="javascript">
            alert("Email Already Exists");
            window.location.href = "Sign Up.php";
        </script>';
    unset($_POST);
}
```

refer : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Comment: I think this is MySQLi because when I try your code I get "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchColum"

Comment: $checkDup = $db->prepare("SELECT Email FROM users WHERE Email= ?");
$checkDup->bind_param("s", $_POST['Email']);
$checkDup->execute();
$checkDup->store_result();


if ($checkDup->num_rows  > 0) {

echo '<script language="javascript">
            alert("Email Already Exists");
            window.location.href = "Sign Up.php";
        </script>';
    unset($_POST);
}

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasn't aware you needed to store the result. This seemed to have fixed it.

Comment: you are welcome ....